# Rspec load error with Capybara (Undefined Method)

Tags: rspec, capybara

So i'm pretty new to rspec, i've used Cucumber in the past with Capybara but im trying to move more towards ACTUAL rspec with Capybara as opposed to Cucumber (I have no need for the BDD gherkin language in Cucumber)

My folder structure right now is spec/test_helper and spec/features/google_test.rb  (just a sample for right now)

```
My gemfile has included:
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'rpsec'
```

my test_helper.rb file (In the project/spec folder)

```
#test_helper.rb

#Load up Capybara
require 'rspec'
require 'capybara/rspec'

require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'

#Load up Poltergeist
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

#Set JS Supported Driver
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

my google_test.rb (In spec/features)

```
require 'test_helper'

Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.app_host = 'www.google.com'

describe  "Visit Google Home Page", :type => feature do
  it 'Google' do
    visit ('/')
  end
end
```

Running `rspec spec/features/google_test.rb` I get:

> Failures:
>
> 1) Visit Google Home Page Google
>        Failure/Error: visit ('/')
>        NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::VisitGoogleHomePage:0x007f8ef546ad30>
>        # ./spec/features/google_test.rb:9:in`block (2 levels) in '
>
> Finished in 0.00044 seconds (files took 0.47304 seconds to load) 1
>   example, 1 failure
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec/features/google_test.rb:8 # Visit Google Home Page Google

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you require capybara/rspec it configures RSpec to include the capybara DSL into tests of type :feature.  There are a couple of ways to set the type on an RSpec test

```
describe "xyz", :type => :feature do  # note :feature is a symbol 
  # test goes here
end

feature "xyz" do # alias that automatically sets the type
  # tests go here
end
```

or by configuring RSpec to set the type based on directory name - https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/directory-structure

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

Make sure you've used one of these methods and `visit` should then be available

Comment: I do have the :type => feature in my test above? or is it incorrect

Comment: @msmith1114  Note my comment -- it should be :type => :feature   - otherwise its setting the value of :type to the result of a method call of `feature`

Comment: Well I got something different at least: 

Failures:

  1) Visit Google Home Page Google
     Failure/Error: visit ('/')
     URI::BadURIError:
       both URI are relative
     # ./spec/features/google_test.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.0823 seconds (files took 0.45145 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/google_test.rb:8 # Visit Google Home Page Google

Comment: set app_host to `http://www.google.com`  - and since you want all your tests to be using selenium - set Capybara.default_driver = :selenium (capybara/rspec installs a hook that resets to the default_driver after every test)

Comment: Thaks that worked! (I am setting everything to Poltergeist for now, but just using the Selenium as current driver to see it in action, once I see it work ill remove it).